# Hibernate delete using criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Can I use Criteria to delete records from my tables?

For example,

```
Criteria toDelete = session.createCriteria(Car.class, "car").createAlias("car.wheel", "wheel");
toDelete.add(Restrictions.eq("brand", "Toyota"));
toDelete.add(Restrictions.eq("wheel.brand", "BBS");
toDelete.add(Restrictions.gt("date_of_purchase", someDay);
toDelete.add(Restrictions.between("cost", 3000, 5000);
```

How can I use toDelete criteria to delete the records that I am interested in? An inefficient way would be to query for the ids using the toDelete criteria, then delete Car objects from there.
Also, can I know how many objects have I deleted?

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade your hibernate version to a version that implements JPA 2.1 (Hibernate starts JPA 2.1 on version 4.3.11.Final - [Hibernate Downloads](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/))

Once you have upgraded, you can use **CriteriaDelete** to do what you want. here is a small example: [Example](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you cannot do that because Hibernate does not support. 
As a replacement, you can use something like:

    
String hql = "delete from User where UserName = :name";
    
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    
query.setString("name", "User 9");
    
int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
    
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowCount);

Best regards,
Hung NGUYEN